# Rust Type mismatch when pattern matching on File::create()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to pattern match when a file doesn't exist, wherein it would be created and then returned but the compiler is expecting '()', I'm not sure how to get it to expect the correct return type of File.

```rust
let mut file = match File::open(&path) {
    Err(_) => match File::create(&path) {
        Err(e) => panic!("issue reading or creating file: {}", e),
        Ok(mut file) => {
            let msg: &str = "Project Paths:\n";
            let f = match file.write_all(msg.as_bytes()) {
                Err(e) => panic!("issue initializing: {}", e),
                Ok(_) => file,
            };
            return f;
        }
    }
    Ok(file) => file,
};
```

i was able to get it to create the file if it doesn't exist but trying to get it to write and then return the file seems to be tricky as the `Err(_)` expects `()` as a return type

```rust
let mut file = match File::open(path) {
    Err(_) => match File::create(path) {
        Err(e) => panic!("issue reading or creating file: {}", e),
        Ok(_) => File::open(path)
            .unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("reading file issue{}", e)),
    },
    Ok(file) => file,
};
```

Comment: Can you include the *exact* error text you're getting as well?

Comment: The `return f` is likely the problem. That should be just `f`.

Comment: You might find this code is easier to write using the `if let Err(e) = file.write_all(...)` instead of having to constantly pass back things like `file`.

Comment: I think the issue is that the write_all returns a result and it was expecting a '()' which I don't fully understand, I got somewhat of the desired result minus the added boilerplate message with
`File::open(path).unwrap_or_else(|e| panic!("reading file issue{}", e)),`

Comment: Your first `Err(_)` branch has type `()`. Your `Ok(file)` path has the file type. This is a contradiction you need to fix. I'd suggest `f` instead of `return f` as the `return` bails out and leaves no type behind.

Comment: Multi-line code blocks don't work in comments, alas.

Comment: That's the crux of the issue I'm not sure why the `Err(_)` has return type `()` taking out the writing and just creating and returning the opened file works but when I try to write to the file the branch starts expecting `()`

Comment: Look at what you have in that branch: A `panic!()` and a `return`. Neither of those has the same type as your `Ok()` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more compact version might look like:

```rust
let mut file = File::open(path)
    .or_else(|_| File.create(path))
    .expect(format!("issue reading or creating file: {}", e));
```

Where you can get most of that done in one shot. You can always switch to a more `panic!` driven style, but in practice you'll want to steer towards propagation via `Result` using `?`, like:

```rust
let mut file = File::open(path).or_else(|_| File.create(path))?;
```

Where that function just propagates the error up the chain to something else that handles it, `panic!` or otherwise.

Comment: You can do even better using `OpenOptions`: `create` will open the file if it exists and create it if not. You can then combine that with the relevant write mode (`append`, `write`, or `truncate`) depending on needs.